# How to loop through strings: stringsim in R

Tags: r

I'm new to R but need it for a single specific research question. How do I loop through a list of strings using the stringsim function in the StringDist package?

I have tried Googling for answers but have not found any that seem to fit my question. I apologise for what is probably a very simple question - I hope to learn R properly in the future but only need it for this one thing in my current project. I can do it manually, string by string, but if anyone would take pity on me and help, I'd greatly appreciate it.

I need to use stringsim to compare each string in a list of strings to a canonical string. And return, for each comparison, the stringsim value between 0 and 1.

So, compare 'ABCDEFG' with 'ABCFFDKJLJ' and with 'LKJASJLKJI' and with 'CCDETT' etc., and return for each of those comparisons a value between 0 and 1 using stringsim.

Comment: Could you provide sample data, code and expand more on the logic? What does a value between 0 and 1 mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`outer` can be used to get all pairwise similarities of elements of a vector.

```
library(stringdist)

x <- c('ABCDEFG', 'ABCFFDKJLJ', 'LKJASJLKJI', 'CCDETT')
outer(x, x, stringsim)
#          [,1] [,2] [,3]      [,4]
#[1,] 1.0000000  0.4  0.1 0.4285714
#[2,] 0.4000000  1.0  0.1 0.2000000
#[3,] 0.1000000  0.1  1.0 0.0000000
#[4,] 0.4285714  0.2  0.0 1.0000000
```

Or, to make it more readable,

```
sim <- outer(x, x, stringsim)
print(sim, digits = 2)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,] 1.00  0.4  0.1 0.43
#[2,] 0.40  1.0  0.1 0.20
#[3,] 0.10  0.1  1.0 0.00
#[4,] 0.43  0.2  0.0 1.00
```

Comment: Brilliant! Can I set the “method” stringsim uses as well if I do it with outer? Here, method is the type of similarity algorithm stringsim uses for its comparisons (eg, method = “lcs”)

Comment: @user12134460 Pass it after the function name, for instance, `outer(x, x, stringsim, method = 'dl')`.